# managedObjectContext giving an error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

For some reason I'm getting an error at the `managedObjectContext =` section in line 9. Here's the code I have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Setup Patterned Background
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Textured Background.png"]];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        managedObjectContext = [(ZAPAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }
    self.napkinsArray = [ZAPNapkinDrafts getNapkinDrafts:self.managedObjectContext];
}
```

Here's what the error states is the reason:

`reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you have made changes to your data model, and are trying to load old data from the persistent store.  You can delete your app from the device/simulator and try to reload it.  That should fix the problem.

You should look up Core Data persistent store migration since you won't be able to delete all your data in a production app.

Here is a quick overview of Core Data migration:

http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/04/ios-core-data-migration/

Answer (score 0):

You have run the app, generated a store on disk, then updated the model and tried to run the app again (so the old store will be reloaded). Either the change you made to the model is too big for the migration you have enabled or you don't have any migration enabled.

Simple fix: delete the app and reinstall it.

Long term fix: implement model versioning and migration.